# Does the consistency part of the CAP theorem apply to updates and not first-time writes?

Tags: nosql, distributed-databases, riak, consistency

Using this definition of the CAP theorem:

> **Consistency** All database clients see the same data, even with concurrent updates.
>
> **Availability** All database clients are able to access some version of the data.
>
> **Partition tolerance** The database can be split over multiple servers.

My understanding is by data they mean a row in the database.

If I choose a database which is AP and I have a table whose rows never get updates after the initial insert (say for example a log table), will that be consistent, available and partition tolerant?

Comment: I suggest that you work hard (! :-) ) and read Michael Stonebraker's writings on this area. Basically, he argues that NoSQL is throwing the baby out with bathwater and that throwing out ACID is throwing out the C - which he argues is much more important than A - since these days, network outages are so rare. He further argues that when your ordinary joe soap programmer tries to overcome this, they will fail. It's easier to overcome a failure in A (hardware) than C (fallible human programmers). Your question doesn't make sense - if the network fails, local updates will not be mirrored.